# How does the desktop version of Wikipedia derive its related articles?

Tags: wikipedia, related-content

On the bottom of the mobile version of the Wikipedia article for [mule deer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_deer), three related articles are listed, with a picture next to each of them.

On the other hand, the [desktop version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_deer) does not list any related articles, which means that the related articles in the mobile view are not taken from the article source code.

So, how are the mobile view’s related articles chosen? Are they picked automatically using some heuristic?

Answer (score 0):

They are the top results from an Elasticsearch [morelikethis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query, which itself is mainly a [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) search (that is, it returns documents which have similar rare words). There is a way for editors to manually override it but it's rarely done.